# The phone of a new contact showed my name without having me as contact yet

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, android

I am using an iPhone 12 Mini, with the latest software updates. Met someone today and we exchanged the contacts, but something funny happened:

1. I gave him my phone to enter his name, phone and email
2. I called him on the number he wrote (my new added contact)
3. My name was displayed on his phone.

How was this possible? I think he uses Android, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like basic Caller ID, Its not a new feature, but if you don't want your name showing up on others devices, you can get a private number.

Yes, I forgot territory is also a big factor. In Canada it is name and number and sometimes location the number is based in.
Also most current devices have options to keep your name and number private if you want. But the guaranteed way is to go through your carrier.

Comment: Can you please add more details? Is it a standard at carrier level or it is a feature from the phone operating systems?

Comment: It is generally a feature implemented at the carrier level, as an "add on" or a feature, some carriers will charge extra for it, but in my experience its usually included in the basic plans. But the feature only lets you see names of people calling, it doesn't make yours visible. 
If you want your name to be private, you have to get a private number usually.

Comment: This may be provider or territory limited. Caller ID in the UK is the phone number, no associated name. You can suppress the ID being sent, but many people won't answer unknown caller.